# How can I get the coordinates of a click in a plot on python side?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a plot with circles on it and I want users to be able to select circles and then I want to do some stuff on python side depending on the circle.

I have tried JS callbacks but I get the error:

> WARNING:bokeh.embed.util: You are generating standalone HTML/JS
>   output, but trying to use real Python callbacks (i.e. with on_change
>   or on_event). This combination cannot work. Only JavaScript callbacks
>   may be used with standalone output. For more information on JavaScript
>   callbacks with Bokeh, see:
>
> http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html
>   Alternatively, to use real Python callbacks, a Bokeh server
>   application may be used. For more information on building and running
>   Bokeh applications, see:
>   http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Here's some code if you want to try to do it.

````
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("openurl.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source)```
````

Comment: The code above does not have any callbacks at all, either JS or Python, so it can't be representative of the code that is causing the warning. Please update the code in the question to be a complete, minimal example that reproduces the warning by itself.

Comment: You can not call a python function if you use output_file to generate a HTML file. If you want to call python function, you need use bokeh server.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quite understand your question, but you can use hover tool to add interaction, or LabelSet to display your x/y along with the dots.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="tap, reset, hover", title="Click 
the Dots", tooltips = [('x', '@x'),('y','@y')])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source)
show(p)
```